# Canvas onmouseover add opacity square

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have been trying for days to add a square on the cursor pointer of the mouse over a canvas.

When my mouse move i need to display a square (with opacity 0.7) without changing initial canvas.

If someone can help ?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#d1defa";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial version was very buggy so after a little thought and looking into using css variables and [discovering this](https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/), I modified the original version and arrived at the following which seems to work ok ( in Google Chrome anyway ):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Position square over canvas at cursor position</title>
        <style>
            :root{
                /* set some initial values for the css variables */
                --width:50px;
                --px:0px;
                --py:0px;
                --bw:0px;
                --display:block;
                cursor:crosshair;
            }

            canvas{
                width:300px;
                height:300px;
                border:var(--bw) solid black;
                border-radius:0.5rem;
                display:inline-block;
                position:absolute;
                margin:10rem;
            }

            #overlay{
                position:absolute;
                left:var(--px);
                top:var(--py);

                width:var(--width);
                height:var(--width);
                display:var(--display);

                opacity:0.7;
                background-color:red;
                border:var(--bw) solid black;
                border-radius:0.5rem;
                cursor:crosshair;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                let canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
                let ctxt=canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctxt.fillStyle = '#d1defa';
                    ctxt.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

                let bounds=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                const id='overlay';
                const width=50;
                const bw=2;


                /* modify initial values of css variables */
                let root=document.documentElement;
                    root.style.setProperty( '--width', width+'px' );
                    root.style.setProperty( '--px', bounds.left+'px' );
                    root.style.setProperty( '--py', bounds.top+'px' );
                    root.style.setProperty( '--bw', bw+'px' );

                let img=new Image();
                    img.onload=()=>{
                        ctxt.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
                    }
                    img.src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/16/38/pumpkin-151302_960_720.png';



                const createsquare=function(id){
                    let div=document.getElementById(id);
                    if( div ) return div;
                    else {
                        div=document.createElement('div');
                        div.id=id;
                        canvas.parentNode.appendChild( div );
                        return div;
                    }
                };


                /* create the overlay */
                createsquare( id );

                /* find the accurate position of the cursor */
                const mousemovehandler=function( event ){
                    let e=event || window.event;
                    let d=( e.target && e.target.ownerDocument ) || document;
                        d=d.documentElement;
                    let b=d.body;
                    e.pageX=e.clientX + ( d + d.scrollLeft || b && b.scrollLeft || 0 ) - ( d && d.clientLeft || b && b.clientLeft || 0 );
                    e.pageY=e.clientY + ( d && d.scrollTop || b && b.scrollTop || 0 ) - ( d && d.clientTop || b && b.clientTop || 0 );
                    return {
                        x:e.pageX,
                        y:e.pageY
                    };
                };

                /* listen for mouse events */
                root.addEventListener( 'mousemove',(e)=>{
                    let obj=mousemovehandler( e );
                    let px=obj.x - ( width / 2 ) - bw;
                    let py=obj.y - ( width / 2 ) - bw;
                    if( 
                        ( obj.x > bounds.left ) && ( obj.x - bw < bounds.right + bw )
                            &&
                        ( obj.y + bw > bounds.top + bw ) && ( obj.y - bw < bounds.bottom + bw )
                    ){
                        /* set the position of the overlay */
                        root.style.setProperty('--display', 'block');
                        root.style.setProperty('--px', px +'px');
                        root.style.setProperty('--py', py +'px');
                    } else {
                        /* hide the overlay */
                        root.style.setProperty('--display', 'none');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what i was looking for !! Thanks it works for me

Comment: I'm glad that it helped - had a bit of fun playing with this too so all good. Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: I've read css-tricks article and it's so cool to see that you can update css variable, thanks sharing this new method

Comment: Hello, after integration , i'm unable to click hover the canvas, because of the div that catch event onclick ... so is it possible to only change opacity of a square of the canvas and restore the canvas color. I use the canvas to draw so i have to be able to draw if i click....i don't know if it's clear ?